# Table structure for Product Attribute

Tags: php, magento-1

I am creating an attribute for product called supplier(Select).
**Question 1**
in which table the values of the supplier attribute are saving While adding the product?

**Question 2**
i want to retrieve the orders product according to supplier attribute.is their any possibilities to filter order according to this supplier selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1**

`eav_attribute` is the table where attribute is stored and options against attribute is stored in `eav_attribute_option` table. And the product table where you'll find both the *attribute* and *value* is  `catalog_product_entity_int`

**Answer 2**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
->getCollection()
->getProduct()
->addAttributeToFilter('supplier', array('like' => '%A%'));  //'%A%' will be your search criteria
```